# Ajax not working on IE

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Got this website --> http://www.secureshop.gr/POOL/acrosshotels/website/ 
If you check on the left sidebar there is the "find a hotel" sidebar where when you choose location from the drop down menu, the Hotel menu changes the options. This works with ajax. The problem is that it's not working with all versions of IE. When you choose a destination, the hotel drop down menu is empty/blank. 
The javascript code is this. Pretty simple and works onclick of the destinations options

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function selecthotel(str)   {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }else  {

      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)    {

        document.getElementById("hotelselection").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
    }

    if(str == 0) {
        str = 0;
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/ajaxlocationsearch.php?location="+str+"&language=<?php echo $language; ?>",true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    }

</script>
```

The ajax file is this

```
$language = $_GET["language"]; 
  $location = $_GET['location'];

if($location == "0") {

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from eshop_articles where
category='/WEBSITE/SEARCHENGINE/HOTELS' order by
appearance",$link_id);  

}else {

    $result = mysql_query("Select * from eshop_articles where
category='/WEBSITE/SEARCHENGINE/HOTELS' and
short_description='$location' order by appearance",$link_id);   

} ?>

<option value="0"><?php $a = $language."_choose_hotel"; echo ${$a};
?></option>

<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {    ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row['appearance']; ?>"><?php echo
$row['title']; ?></option>

<?php } ?>
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: why dont you use $.ajax()...?

Comment: jQuery Ajax is not supported in IE 5, which is fairly common despite the fact that it's a big security risk, that's why creating a class for Ajax functions with XMLHttpRequest and ActiveXObject is essential.

Comment: I have IE 11. Still not working

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some testing and I found out that your code had some issues with the structure. You should always have the code properly formatted in order to find errors and problems faster. I formatted your code and found some problems with nesting and your query.

I would also like to warn you that you had a pretty serious SQL injection problem, which I fixed in this code by using prepared statements and a small extra `preg_replace` to strip all unwanted characters from the query and table in general. You should totally go and learn a little bit more about preventing SQL injections. There are great topics here that are dedicated to the subject and I made a list of these articles to you:

- [stackoverflow.com - How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
- [php.net - SQL Injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Here is the code I formatted and fixed. I have tested it by using no parameter, an empty parameter, a value that does not exist in the database, and a value that does exist in the database. Each one returned the value accordingly: three first ones return null, while the real query returns true; in this case it returns "No hotels available" if none found, or a list of these hotels if found. If the database query fails, it will by default return null, and then return "No hotels found".

I am sorry for changing the code layout a little bit, feel free to edit it back as you like, that's up to you. I highly recommend proper formatting however (might have been because of your code editor as well).

**index.php**

```
<?php
    $language = "en";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hotel Selection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="hotelselection">
            <option value="null">No hotels available</option>
        </select>
        
        <script>
            function selecthotel(str) {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }else{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("hotelselection").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                
                if (typeof(str) == "undefined" || str == null) {
                    str = "";
                }
                
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "run.php?location=" + str + "&language=<?php echo($language); ?>", true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
            
            selecthotel();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**run.php**

```
<?php
    $phrases = array(
        "en_error_db" => "No hotels available...",
        "en_choose_hotel" => "Choose a hotel..."
    );
    
    $link_id = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($link_id)) {
        die("Error occurred when attempting to connect to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ": " . mysqli_connect_error() . ").");
        error_log("Error occurred when attempting to connect to database (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ": " . mysqli_connect_error() . ").");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    $language_raw = isset($_GET["language"]) ? $_GET["language"] : "en"; 
    $location_raw = isset($_GET['location']) ? $_GET["location"] : "";
    
    $language = preg_replace("/[^\w.-]/", "", $language_raw);
    $location = preg_replace("/[^\w.-]/", "", $location_raw);
    
    if (empty($location)) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `eshop_articles` WHERE `category` = '/WEBSITE/SEARCHENGINE/HOTELS' ORDER BY `appearance` ASC";
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `eshop_articles` WHERE `category` = '/WEBSITE/SEARCHENGINE/HOTELS' AND `short_description` = ? ORDER BY `appearance` ASC";
    }
    
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link_id, $query)) {
        if (!empty($location)) {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $location);
        }
        
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        
    // Thanks to Bruce Martin on php.net for the SELECT * via _fetch (http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#107034)
        $metaResults = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
        $fields = mysqli_fetch_fields($metaResults);
        $statementParams = "";
        
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $statementParams .= (empty($statementParams) ? "\$column['" . $field->name . "']" : ", \$column['" . $field->name . "']");
        }
        
        $statment = "\$stmt->bind_result($statementParams);";
        eval($statment);
        print('<option value="0">' . $phrases[(isset($phrases[$language . "_choose_hotel"]) ? $language : "en") . "_choose_hotel"] . '</option>');
        
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            print('<option value="' . $column['appearance'] . '">' . $column['title'] . '</option>');
        }
        
        exit(1);
    }else{
        print('<option value="0">' . $phrases[(isset($phrases[$language . "_choose_hotel"]) ? $language : "en") . "_error_db"] . '</option>');
        error_log("The script was unable to prepare a MySQLi statement (" . $query . ").");
        exit(1);
    }
?>
```

I switched over to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) database extension instead of your [deprecated MySQL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). It should no longer return PHP errors over PHP error logs. I highly recommend switching to [MySQL PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) if just possible. It's very simple, easy and works a lot better in my opinion!

Also, a note on your XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject usage: if you want to be able to support IE 5, create a class for that and load the script if the client is using that browser, otherwise use [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), which is very easy to use and you will not need to worry about query strings or so. The reason for having the ActiveXObject script out there, is because jQuery is not supported on IE 5, which is a common browser despite the known security issues. IE 5 is used by old computers, some banks, offices and other businesses that have not looked into the security details.

Hopefully this helped you.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your time, i ll try it in a couple of hours but i think it will work cause it looks fine. Thanks again. :)

Comment: You are welcome :-) When you get to it, let me know if it does not work, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @satafaka: I suggest re-copying the code now. I went ahead and just revised the code to follow prepared statements :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ajax-requests are cached in Internet Explorer. Try to delete the cache and then add a random parameter to the request-URL:

```
var url = "http://example.com/ajax.php?random="+new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Ok i did this, you can check it with firebug. Now what? Still not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't reinvent the wheel, there are some mature cross-browsers solutions out there already.

You should try using jQuery library and it's `ajax` method.

```
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
```

If you don't want to use a library you can find some solutions to your problem already, it involves creating different types of objects for IE:

```
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html
```

Internet Explorer caches content a lot, so you might need to force it to grab new data instead of taking it from the cache. You can add a GET parameter with a timestamp which is generated client side to the URL to which you're pointing.

In jQuery you can simply do it like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://example.com/",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
       // do something here
    }
});
```

Without jQuery you would need to add it manually to the url:

```
var url = "http://example.com" + "?_=" + (newDate()).getTime();
```